# Evaluating NaiveBayes classifier by constructing confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, confusion-matrix

I am trying to build a confusion matrix for blood Pressure patient where in actual number of patients predicted Blood pressure=0.18 and Not .82
Now the Naive Bayes classifier has Predicted no of patients having Blood pressure=0.410 and not 0.0913.I am new to this and i am not getting the idea of how to construct confusion matrix for the above problem.Please anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the confusion matrix, you need to know the *agreement* on individual test samples.

You cannot compute it from the frequencies of the individual estimators alone.

Mathematically, you need the **joint distribution**, but you gave the edge distributions only.